# Illegal Operation on a Directory with Unknown Broccoli Plugin

Tags: ember.js

Output from `ember version --verbose && npm --version`:

```
ember-cli: 2.12.1
http_parser: 2.7.0
node: 6.10.2
v8: 5.1.281.98
uv: 1.9.1
zlib: 1.2.11
ares: 1.10.1-DEV
icu: 58.2
modules: 48
openssl: 1.0.2k
os: darwin x64
3.10.10
```

When I try `ember s` I have the following error,

```
Livereload server on http://localhost:49153
Serving on http://localhost:4200/
The Broccoli Plugin: [object Object] failed with:
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.readSync (fs.js:732:19)
    at tryReadSync (fs.js:487:20)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:535:19)
    at /Users/li-xinyang/Desktop/XX_MemoCycle_Firebase/node_modules/broccoli-flatiron/index.js:33:16
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at readDirectory (/Users/li-xinyang/Desktop/XX_MemoCycle_Firebase/node_modules/broccoli-flatiron/index.js:28:31)
    at /Users/li-xinyang/Desktop/XX_MemoCycle_Firebase/node_modules/broccoli-flatiron/index.js:21:15
    at tryCatch (/Users/li-xinyang/Desktop/XX_MemoCycle_Firebase/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:539:12)
    at invokeCallback (/Users/li-xinyang/Desktop/XX_MemoCycle_Firebase/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:554:13)

The broccoli plugin was instantiated at:
undefined
```

Below is a list of `devDependencies`,

package.json File

```
{
  "name": "memo-cycle",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "A study tool for serious learner",
  "license": "MIT",
  "author": "",
  "directories": {
    "doc": "doc",
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "repository": "",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "ember build",
    "start": "ember server",
    "test": "ember test"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "broccoli-asset-rev": "^2.4.5",
    "ember-ajax": "^2.4.1",
    "ember-cli": "2.12.1",
    "ember-cli-app-version": "^2.0.0",
    "ember-cli-babel": "^5.1.7",
    "ember-cli-dependency-checker": "^1.3.0",
    "ember-cli-eslint": "^3.0.0",
    "ember-cli-gravatar": "^3.8.1",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars": "^1.1.1",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile": "^0.3.6",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.4.1",
    "ember-cli-qunit": "^3.1.0",
    "ember-cli-sass": "^6.1.2",
    "ember-cli-shims": "^1.0.2",
    "ember-cli-sri": "^2.1.0",
    "ember-cli-uglify": "^1.2.0",
    "ember-export-application-global": "^1.0.5",
    "ember-in-viewport": "^2.1.1",
    "ember-inline-svg": "^0.1.10",
    "ember-load-initializers": "^0.6.0",
    "ember-paper": "^1.0.0-alpha.19",
    "ember-power-select": "^1.6.1",
    "ember-power-select-with-create": "^0.3.1",
    "ember-resolver": "^2.0.3",
    "ember-route-action-helper": "^2.0.2",
    "ember-simple-auth": "^1.2.2",
    "ember-source": "~2.12.0",
    "loader.js": "^4.2.3"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 4"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

It was working fine before my last to commit. What I have done in the last two commits are I remove all `.DS_Store` files in the last commit and added Firebase deploy config files and install cloud function dependencies via Yarn in the last second commit.

What I have tried to resolve the issues, but the issue persists.

1) Delete all node modules via `rm -rf node_modules` and re-install them `npm install` (dependencies were installed via Yarn)

2) Remove the project and clone from the origin

3) Revert back to early commit (issue persists even I revert back to the `initial commit` and re-install all the dependencies of course)

4) Restart Mac

5) Update `.ember-cli` file and re-run `ember init` setup process

Comment: Did you try this https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/3087#issuecomment-71797959 ?

Comment: Yes, I did. See what I have tried 5th item.

Comment: `so I have now deleted the .ember-cli folder in my home directory. Followed the procedure again from: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/releases and it is now working again.
Thanks again guys. I had not thought about the .ember-cli folder in my home` the above comment is saying `delete .ember-cli folder in my home directory` and do ember-cli project update step.

Comment: I do not have a ember-cli in my home dir and try to do the update step again

Comment: I have completed the steps again but issue persists. If you want I can invite you to the priviate repo

Comment: I am not familiar and i haven't experienced with this issue..ember folks will ask for more details if required in your [github issue](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/6981)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues is caused by

> That plugin looks like it was built for an older version of broccoli, but the basic problem seems that its write function doesn't handle symlinks to directories.

See this GitHub issue for more details

https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/6981